# mongodb - How to access lookup results in another lookup in aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to search in lookup based on the previous lookup but no luck.

I get all the results I'm supposed to get but office is returning always an empty array
what am i missing here?

```js
query[2] = {
            $lookup: {
                from: "users",
                let: {sales_agent: "$sales_agent"},
                pipeline: [
                    {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ['$_id', '$$sales_agent']}}},
                    {$project: {_id: 1, username: 1, office: 1}},
                ],
                as: "sales_agent"
            }
        };
        query[3] = {
            $lookup: {
                from: "offices",
                let: {office: "$sales_agent.0.office"}, //this value supposed to be come from the previous lookup
                pipeline: [
                    {$match: {$expr: {$eq: ['$_id', '$$office']}}},
                    {$project: {_id: 1, city: 1,}},
                ],
                as: "office"
            }
        };
```

Comment: Would be great if you could show us the schemas for the above collections in question, better if you could show some sample input data with the expected output. This will help you get quality answers without the need to clarify your question further.

Comment: Try `let: {elem: {$arrayElemAt:["$sales_agent", 0]}}` and                    `{$match: {$expr: {$eq: ['$_id', '$$elem.office']}}}` in second lookup.

Comment: @Veeram it worked!!!!! thanks put your comment as an answer so i can accept it. thanks(:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$arrayElemAt` to access the element from previous lookup array.

Try

```
let: {elem: {$arrayElemAt:["$sales_agent", 0]}}
```

&

```
{$match: {$expr: {$eq: ['$_id', '$$elem.office']}}}
```

or in one modification

```
let: {office: {$let:{vars:{elem:{$arrayElemAt:["$sales_agent", 0]}}, in:"$$elem.office"}}}
```